# In NebulaGraph Database, Can I modify --rocksdb_rate_limit dynamically?

Tags: nebula-graph

I want to change the compact rate dynamically. Is it possible?
In the daytime and nighttime, this rate should be different.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to change the compact rate dynamically. Nebula Graph cannot change this parameter dynamically. It is set in the config file.